# Installing npm modules for node package

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm making a npm package as a test, and i want to install typescript. This makes a `node_modules` folder which is not needed. How do i install npm depencices without `node_modules`?

Comment: If your package needs NPM dependencies, a `node_modules` folder is needed. If you don't want these published with your package, but rather installed as dependencies, simply add `node_modules` to .gitignore or .npmignore -- if this helps you I will add it as an answer

Comment: One can install TypeScript globally with `npm i typescript -g` -- however I do suggest installing it as a dev dependency rather than globally: `npm i typescript -D`. If one sends their package to the npm registry and uses it, dev dependencies do not get downloaded, but one would still need it to build the js files that are used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is practically impossible to avoid making a `node_modules` folder, as it contains the source code for the module, downloaded onto your hard drive.

---

However, even though it's impossible to avoid downloading `node_modules`, you can add it to an ignore file (such as `.gitignore`).

If you want to avoid `node_modules` in both Git and npm (recommended), then you only have to create a `.gitignore` file, as npm will ignore everything specified in the `.gitignore` file.

```
node_modules
```

Simply add the above in `.gitignore`.

If you only want it to ignore `node_modules` in npm and *not* Git (not recommended), then create a `.npmignore` file, and add the following:

```
node_modules
```

---

In summary, even though it isn't possible to remove `node_modules`, you can ignore it!

Comment: Well, when an npm package is downloaded, all of the files (besides `package.json`) are downloaded into a `node_modules` folder. I was wondering if there was a way to download a custom package with already existing packages pre-installed.